# Mass search / replace string from ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, replace, search-and-replace, strings

I am in the process of selling a network of 60 sites, they all have adsense with the same publisher id (google_ad_client="pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") in all the files in the /home/ folder.

How can I do a mass search/replace from ssh to change my id to the buyer id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to ssh to each machine and make that change?  Should be pretty straightfoward with ssh and expect.  Check out this [stackoverflow question about that approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/459182/212247).  Basically you just need to use expect to automate the ssh logins and then run something like this on every server (all via expect):

> find /home/ -type f -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/pub-xxxxxxx/pub-12345/'

that will use sed to edit every file in-place in /home (and no lower in the tree) and replace occurrences of the first string with the latter.

If this is more than a one-time thing you can look into automating this more cleanly, like setting up passwordless ssh logins to eliminate the expect step. However if I understand your question correctly you are really looking for a one-time solution, which is why I say use expect this way.

Comment: Thanks that helped, I actually only need to login on one machine as root, it's a dedicated server.

Comment: Oh ha, then that's a lot easier.  Just log in and run a sed script!

Comment: For me, it says `find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it). Please specify options before other arguments.
`
I'm on centos 6!
Thank you!

Comment: Ok then just try `find -maxdepth 1 /home/ -maxdepth1 -print0 etc`